# CloneNotSupportedException in actionPerformed

Tags: java, jbutton, clone, throw, throws

In my actionPerformed method i'm calling "copy()" who clones objects, but the compiler gives me this error: "java.awt.event.ActionListener; overridden method does not throw java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException", what can i do?

```
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
      copy(); ...
```

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

[You can not add throwed checked exception to a method while overriding it.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_overriding.htm)

> [...] the overriding method should not throw checked exceptions that
>   are new or broader than the ones declared by the overridden method.
>   [...]

You have to handle it.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    //code
    try {
        copy();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException cnse) {
        cnse.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```